# How to make Firefox Developer Tools display FirePHP messages within console?

Tags: php, firefox, firephp

I decided to try working with the Firefox Developer Edition. I am writing PHP code for a Joomla site and use Firebug & FirePHP to send data to the console.
While that works fine with the standard Firefox (36.0.4), I get no output with the Developer Edition (38.0a2).

Am I missing something? Should that work OK?

Comment: Please upload your code, post specific results, and list your debugging efforts.

Comment: Hi @JunYoungGwak That is difficult.  The code I use on many sites is, for example fb($form->data,'form data from a joomla page',FirePHP::INFO);  That code should (and in FF36.0.4 does) send a copy of the content of $form->data to the console.  There is not output with the developer edition.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, working on Firefox Standard but not on Developer edition. AFAICT it's due to Firebug now working nicely with firebug 3 (which is the one actually working with the Dev edition due to the multiprocessor e10s feature). I guess then there is an issue with FirePHP and Firebug 3 (actually in alpha)

Answer (score 8):

Actually after digging a bit around, found that Firefox Developer Edition already has an integrated [server side logging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Server). You can implement it via [Chrome Logger](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger), which has also a [PHP extension](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp) available.

Besides that you can try it with the newest version of [FirePHP](https://github.com/firephp/firephp-extension), but as far as I can tell it works only with Firebug 2.x, which doesn't work while Firefox is working in [multi-process mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox).

I got the server loggin console working without an issue with Chrome Logger instead of the FirePHP port. And with Firebug.next I can't make it work.

Comment: You were posting this answer while I was reading this old question. What a coincidence! Two things: Firebug.next is only a theme for the DevTools and FirePHP doesn't work with them, as far as I know. And Firebug 2.x only works when the multi-process mode (aka e10s) is disabled.

Comment: Hehe nice finding then! :) 
Yea I noticed the e10s feature is messing up with Firebug 2.x, unfortunately I tried even disabling e10s and restarting the browser (using the link in the warning popup from Firebug) with no positive results. I eventually found the newest port of the FirePHP extensions which was intended specifically for Firebug.next but then [this issue](https://github.com/firephp/firephp-for-firebug.next/issues/8) stated the exact contrary... (btw thanks for the edits, sometimes I can write really bad ;) )

Comment: Forgot to mention that when you want to download Firebug 2.x from the Firebug website, you need to set the preference `xpinstall.signatures.required` via [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) to `false`. (Background: Since version 43 Firefox [requires all add-ons to be signed](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing), but Firebug is only signed on when you download it from addons.mozilla.org.)

Answer (score 0):

On http://firephp.org/ it says "Coming Soon: FirePHP Extension for Firebug.Next (Firebug 3.0) & **Firefox Developer Tools**" but no date is given.

Comment: Thanks Aba. I must watch for that

Answer (score 0):

FirePHP for Firefox Developer Tools has now been released :

https://github.com/firephp/firephp-for-firefox-devtools

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QuantumPHP.  Browser add-on:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quantumphp/

FirePHP fork that works with the above add-on:

```
composer require frankforte/quantumphp
```

If you do not use composer, you can also follow the instructions here:
https://packagist.org/packages/frankforte/quantumphp